# How to get pentaho report designer and BI server log files?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

We are using Pentaho Report Designer(PRD) Tool and BI server, here in PRD and BI server where and how do we find out log files. We are using Pentaho 7.1.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch PRD/BI server/PDI for the first time it creates .pentaho and .kettle folder inside users directory.

You will be able to find logs inside

```
Users\Your username\.pentaho\logs
Users\Your username\.kettle
```

Check respective folder for more details.